# Bootstrap table-responsive scrollbar locked, cannot scroll

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, adminlte

I am using the following markup. The horizontal scrollbar show up on mobile browsers and also chrome dev tool but is locked to the left side and cannot be dragged or scrolled.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-hover">
        ...
    </table>
</div>
```

There seems to be no additional `css` other than default bootstrap styles. `table.table` has `width: 100%` and `max-width: 100%` but they are from bootstrap. Tried changing them to `width: auto` and `max-width: none !important` but doesn't work.

I am using `Bootstrap 3.3.6` and `AdminLTE 2`

Comment: did you try this  ? `overflow-x:scroll;`

Comment: Adding a JSFiddle might help others better investigate the issue.

Comment: I'm testing my site's layout by making my desktop browsers very narrow. I have identical markup to that shown above. Using Bootstrap 3.3.7. Horizontal scrollbar works correctly in Chrome and Firefox, but the scrollbar is disabled in Edge. While I don't have the answer, I can at least verify that there is a problem in some browsers.